# Users set upload limits to prevent too many large files from being uploaded to the server

Tags: python, gradio

Let users set upload limits to prevent too many large files from being uploaded to the server. This is especially relevant as we release the client as programmatically uploaded files could take up a lot of space on the servers.

This could be a max_file_size parameter to launch().

I tried using the max_file_size parameter in the launch() function.

1.

```
def launch(
        self,
        inline: bool | None = None,
        inbrowser: bool = False,
        share: bool | None = None,
        debug: bool = False,
        max_threads: int = 40,
        auth: Callable | tuple[str, str] | list[tuple[str, str]] | None = None,
        auth_message: str | None = None,
        prevent_thread_lock: bool = False,
        show_error: bool = False,
        server_name: str | None = None,
        server_port: int | None = None,
        *,
        height: int = 500,
        width: int | str = "100%",
        favicon_path: str | None = None,
        ssl_keyfile: str | None = None,
        ssl_certfile: str | None = None,
        ssl_keyfile_password: str | None = None,
        ssl_verify: bool = True,
        quiet: bool = False,
        show_api: bool = True,
        allowed_paths: list[str] | None = None,
        blocked_paths: list[str] | None = None,
        root_path: str | None = None,
        app_kwargs: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
        state_session_capacity: int = 10000,
        share_server_address: str | None = None,
        share_server_protocol: Literal["http", "https"] | None = None,
        max_file_size: int | None = None, #max_file_size parameter added
        _frontend: bool = True,
    ) -> tuple[FastAPI, str, str]:
```

2. But it shows the 'max_file_size not accessed' so I tried further with a few changes.

```
from typing import Callable, List, Any, Literal
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

class YourClass:
    # ... (other class methods and attributes)

    # Mark the changes in the following function
    def launch(
        self,
        upload_file: FileStorage,  # Changed the parameter to explicitly specify it's a file upload
        inline: bool | None = None,
        inbrowser: bool = False,
        share: bool | None = None,
        debug: bool = False,
        max_threads: int = 40,
        auth: Callable | tuple[str, str] | List[tuple[str, str]] | None = None,
        auth_message: str | None = None,
        prevent_thread_lock: bool = False,
        show_error: bool = False,
        server_name: str | None = None,
        server_port: int | None = None,
        *,
        height: int = 500,
        width: int | str = "100%",
        favicon_path: str | None = None,
        ssl_keyfile: str | None = None,
        ssl_certfile: str | None = None,
        ssl_keyfile_password: str | None = None,
        ssl_verify: bool = True,
        quiet: bool = False,
        show_api: bool = True,
        allowed_paths: List[str] | None = None,
        blocked_paths: List[str] | None = None,
        root_path: str | None = None,
        app_kwargs: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
        state_session_capacity: int = 10000,
        share_server_address: str | None = None,
        share_server_protocol: Literal["http", "https"] | None = None,
        max_file_size: int | None = None,  # Added max_file_size parameter
        _frontend: bool = True,
    ) -> tuple[FastAPI, str, str]:
        """
        Launches the specified functionality.

        Args:
            upload_file (FileStorage): The file to be uploaded.
            ... (existing parameters)
            max_file_size (int, optional): The maximum allowed size of the file in bytes.

        Raises:
            ValueError: If the file size exceeds the specified maximum size.

        Returns:
            bool: True if the launch is successful, False otherwise.
        """
        try:
            # Marking the change: using upload_file.filename to get the file name
            print(f"Uploading file: {upload_file.filename}")

            # Your existing code logic for launching functionality

            # Check if max_file_size is specified and enforce the limit
            if max_file_size is not None and upload_file.content_length > max_file_size:
                raise ValueError("File size exceeds the specified maximum size.")

            # Continue with the rest of the launch logic

            # Return True if launch is successful
            return True

        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions or errors during launch
            print(f"Error during launch: {e}")
            return False
```

But this part of code makes the code the code logic below itself unreachable for some reason.